# How to select all elements of the same kind in RichFaces

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, richfaces

As far as I know, there are several functions in RichFaces that allow to get a reference to a "rich:" component by its id from javascript. But in my case I can have arbitrary amount of collapsiblePanels and need a way to expand them all upon a button click. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Richfaces does not offer such a function. You can try to use JQuery to query for the class `.rf-cp` that is common to the `CollapsiblePanel` and try to get it from there.

Of course, since all of the "arbitrary number" of panels will come from your code, I think that maybe it would be safer to, each time a new panel is created by your .xml, you add its id somewhere (Javascript code, hidden field, etc.) and use it from there.

The list of richfaces available functions: http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_2_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html_single/#chap-Component_Reference-Functions

Comment: Thank you for a quick response.I tried to store every panel in an array, it partially worked, for some reason the last panel refuses to expand upon button click and I can't figure out why. I'll try the trick with rf-cp, thanks for the idea!

Comment: Apparently I was storing the reference to the last panel of the list the wrong way. Fixed it and everything works okay now